# 405 (Method Not Allowed) in custom URL Route Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, controller

I got stuck with my ajax POST request.

1. My URL looks like this `localhost/product/list` (if a row is clicked,it will redirect to **page.edit** through a request like this `localhost/product/list/edit/{id}` )
2. When `localhost/product/list/edit/{id}` receives the edit request the response shows an error like `localhost/product/list/edit/update_list 405 (Method Not Allowed)`.
3. I am confused why the URL changes from `localhost/product/list/edit/{id}` to `localhost/product/list/edit/update_list`, I mean the variable `/{id}` is missing.

Console always marks this part in my AJAX **edit.js** as an error.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data: {
        'id': id,
        'judul': judulArtikel,
        'isi': isiArtikel,
         // --- till the end ---
    }
});
```

Here is my **load.js** which loads data from a database.

```
<td><a id='"+result.data[count-1].id+"'' href='list/edit/"+result.data[count-1].id+"' class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></a></td>
```

Here is my `route.php`.

```
Route::get('list/edit/{id}', 'Controller@list_to_edit');
Route::post('/update_list', 'ProductController@update_list');
```

Here is my controller.

```
public function list_to_edit($id){
    $artikel = Artikel::where("id","=",$id)->get();
    return view('page.edit',compact('artikel'));
}
```

Here is my **edit.js**.

```css
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  $('#isi_artikel').summernote({
   height: 300,
   minHeight: 400,
   maxHeight: 400,
   focus: true
  });
  
 $('#btn_submit').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var isiArtikel = $('#isi_artikel').summernote('code');
  var judulArtikel = $('#judul').val();
  var deskripsiArtikel  = $('#deskripsi').val();
  var kategori = $('input[name="etype"]:checked').val();

  if($('#inputpicture').val() == ""){
  
  $.ajaxSetup({
   headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN':$('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content')
   }
  })

  $.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   data: {
    'id'  : id,
    'judul'  : judulArtikel,
    'isi'   : isiArtikel,
    'kategori'  : kategori,
    'deskripsi' : deskripsiArtikel,
    'image'  : null
   },
   dataType: "json",
   url: "update_list",
   beforeSend: function (request) {
          return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("meta[name='csrf_token']").attr('content'));
      },
   success: function(result){
    if(result){
     window.location.href = "kelola";
    }
   },
   error : function(jqXhr) {
          var errors = jqXhr.responseJSON; 
          //console.log(jqXhr);

          errorsHtml = "<div class='alert alert-warning text-center' role='alert'>";

          $.each( errors , function( key, value ) {
              errorsHtml +=  value[0] ; 
              //console.log(value[0]);
          });

          errorsHtml += "</div>";
    
    $('.alerts').html("<div>gila lu</div>");
          $('.alerts').append(errorsHtml).fadeIn(200).fadeToggle(10000).fadeOut(50);
      }
  }, "json");
  }else{
   var ajax = function(imageData){
    requestUploadArtikel(judulArtikel, isiArtikel, kategori, deskripsiArtikel, imageData);
   }

  imageupload($('#inputpicture').get(0), ajax);
  }
       
       
 });

 function requestUploadArtikel(judul, isi, kategori, deskripsi, imageData){
  $.ajaxSetup({
   headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN':$('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content')
   }
  })

  $.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   data: {
    'id'  : id,
    'judul'  : judul,
    'isi'   : isi,
    'kategori'  : kategori,
    'deskripsi' : deskripsi,
    'image'  : imageData
   },
   dataType: "json",
   url: "update_artikel",
   success: function(result){
    if(result){
     window.location.href = "kelola";
    }
   },
   error : function(jqXhr) {
          var errors = jqXhr.responseJSON; 
          //console.log(jqXhr);

          errorsHtml = "<div class='alert alert-warning text-center' role='alert'>";

          $.each( errors , function( key, value ) {
              errorsHtml +=  value[0] ; 
              //console.log(value[0]);
          });

          errorsHtml += "</div>";
    
    $('.alerts').html("<div>gila lu</div>");
          $('.alerts').append(errorsHtml).fadeIn(200).fadeToggle(10000).fadeOut(50);
      }
  }, "json");
 }

 function imageupload(element, ajax){
  console.log('testimageupload');
  
     var elementId = element.id;

     if(element.files && element.files[0]){
         var file = element.files[0];
         var validFileType = ".jpg, .png, .bmp";
         var extension = file.name.substring(file.name.lastIndexOf('.')).toLowerCase();
         $("#"+elementId+"-show").attr('src', "");

         console.log(extension);

         //validatefile
         if(validFileType.toLowerCase().indexOf(extension)<0){
             $("#"+elementId+"-alert").show();
             $("#"+elementId+"-show")
             .attr('style', '')
    .css('height','auto')
             return;
         }
         $("#"+elementId+"-alert").hide();

         //showfile
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.onload = function(e){
          ajax(e.target.result);
         }

         if (reader.readAsDataURL) {reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);}
         else if(reader.readAsDataurl) {reader.readAsDataurl(element.files[0]);}
         else if(reader.readAsDataUrl) {reader.readAsDataUrl(element.files[0]);}

     }
     else{
      console.log('else');
         $(elementId+"-show").attr('src',"");
     }
 }
});
```

here's my **edit.blade.php**

```css
@extends('layout.layout')

@section('css')
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.1/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
@stop

@section('script')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/artikel/edit.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.1/summernote.js"></script>
@stop


@section('content')
 <!-- Main Content -->
 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <h1 class="text-center edittengah">Edit Artikel</h1>
            <div class="alerts"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            @foreach ($artikel as $a_artikel)
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
                <div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Judul Artikel</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Judul Artikel" id="judul" required data-validation-required-message="Harap tuliskan judul artikel." value="{{$a_artikel->judul}}">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                        <label for="inputpicture">Ganti Foto Artikel</label>
                        <input type="file" name="picture" class="" id="inputpicture">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Deskripsi Artikel</label>
                        <textarea name="deskripsi" id="deskripsi" cols="70" rows="5" placeholder="Deskripsi Artikel">{{ $a_artikel->deskripsi }}</textarea>
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Isi</label>
                        <div id="isi_artikel">{!! $a_artikel->content !!}</div>
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row control-group">
               <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                     <label>Jenis Artikel</label>
                     <?PHP if($a_artikel->kategori == "umum"){?>
                            <label><input class="CBumum" type="radio" name="etype" value="umum" checked="true"> Umum </label>
                            <label><input class="CBsh" type="radio" name="etype" value="selfhelp"> Self Help </label>
                            <label><input class="CBact" type="radio" name="etype" value="activites"> Activities </label>
                        <?PHP }
                            elseif($a_artikel->kategori == "selfhelp"){
                        ?>
                            <label><input class="CBumum" type="radio" name="etype" value="umum" > Umum </label>
                            <label><input class="CBsh" type="radio" name="etype" value="selfhelp" checked="true"> Self Help </label>
                            <label><input class="CBact" type="radio" name="etype" value="activites"> Activities </label>
                        <?php } 
                            else{
                        ?>
                            <label><input class="CBumum" type="radio" name="etype" value="umum" > Umum </label>
                            <label><input class="CBsh" type="radio" name="etype" value="selfhelp"> Self Help </label>
                            <label><input class="CBact" type="radio" name="etype" value="activites" checked="true"> Activities </label>
                        <?php }?>
                     
                   
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <hr>
                <br>
                <div id="success"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                        <input class="btn btn-success" id="btn_submit" type="submit">
                    @endforeach

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
@stop
```

Your help is needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKay my bad knowledge in routes,,

my ajax url update :

```
"url" : "/update_list"
```

it must should be

```
"url" : window.location + "/update_list"
```

and my controller from :

```
    Route::post('/update_list', 'Controller@update_post');
```

to

```
    Route::post('kelola/list/{id}/update_list', 'Controller@update_post');
```

'kelola/list/{id}/update_list' refer to my baseUrl before ajax process URL